# Copying the entire telerik docklayout from one page to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, dock

I'm trying to copy the docklayout from one page and try to recreate it in another page.

Here is my code-

**Default.aspx**

```
<div>
<telerik:RadDockLayout ID="dockLayout" runat="server" OnSaveDockLayout="dockLayout_SaveDockLayout">
<telerik:RadDockZone ID="dockZone" runat="server">
<telerik:RadDock ID="dock" runat="server" UniqueName="dock1">
<Commands>
</Commands>
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text="Dock1"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="btnOK" runat="server" Text="OK1" />
</ContentTemplate>
</telerik:RadDock>
</telerik:RadDockZone>
<br /><br />
<telerik:RadDockZone ID="RadDockZone1" runat="server">
<telerik:RadDock ID="RadDock1" runat="server" UniqueName="dock2">
<Commands>
</Commands>
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="Dock2"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="OK2" />
</ContentTemplate>
</telerik:RadDock>
</telerik:RadDockZone>
</telerik:RadDockLayout>
<div style="width:100%;text-align:center">
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" onclick="btnSave_Click" />
</div>
</div>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
protected void dockLayout_SaveDockLayout(object sender, DockLayoutEventArgs e)
{
    List<DockState> dockState = dockLayout.GetRegisteredDocksState();
    JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    Session["dock"] = ser.Serialize(dockState);
}

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("receivingPage.aspx");
}
```

**receivingPage.aspx.cs**

```
public partial class receivingPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private List<DockState> dockStates;
    private RadDockLayout dockLayout;

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        dockLayout = new RadDockLayout();
        dockLayout.LoadDockLayout += new DockLayoutEventHandler(dockLayout_LoadDockLayout);
        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        dockStates = ser.Deserialize<List<DockState>>(Page.Session["dock"].ToString());
        for (int i = 0; i < dockStates.Count; i++)
        {
            RadDock dock = new RadDock();
            dock.ID = string.Format("RadDock{0}", i);
            dock.ApplyState(dockStates[i]);
            dockLayout.Controls.Add(dock);
        }
        this.Controls.Add(dockLayout);
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    void dockLayout_LoadDockLayout(object sender, DockLayoutEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DockState state in dockStates)
        {
            e.Positions[state.UniqueName] = state.DockZoneID;
            e.Indices[state.UniqueName] = state.Index;
        }
    }      
}
```

But I'm getting emtpy docklayout in receivingPage.aspx. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to contact Telerik via the forum or to send a support ticket with a sample project.